# push notifications to a group using Firebase functions

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an app that uses firebase for messaging. I want to use functions to send out push notifications when there is a new message in a group. Unfortunately, I have zero experience with node.js as I don't have a CS background and only a few months of coding experience.

I've tried to piece it together from tutorials I could find, but I'm not even sure if I'm headed in the right direction.

This is for an iOS App if that makes any difference

Here's my firebase structure

[image]

Here's what I have so far

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendPush = functions.database.onWrite(event => {
let projectStateChanged = false;
let projectCreated = false;
let projectData = event.data.val();

if (!event.data.previous.exists()) {
    projectCreated = true;
}
if (!projectCreated && event.data.changed()) {
    projectStateChanged = true;
}
var valueObject = event.data.val();

return loadUsers().then(users => {
    let tokens = [];
    for (let user of users) {
        tokens.push(user.pushToken);
    }
    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: valueObject.RealName,
            body: valueObject.MessageBody,
            sound: 'default',
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
});
 });
function loadUsers() {
let dbRef = event.data.ref.parent.parent.ref('/GroupMembers/');
let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
        let data = snap.val();
        let users = [];
        for (var property in data) {
            users.push(data[property]);
        }
        resolve(users);
    }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
});
return defer;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final working code

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
// console.log(functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/GroupMembers'));
var pushID = ''
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}/messages/{messageID}').onWrite(event => { //THIS IS NOW CORRECT!!

    let projectData = event.data.val();  // this is the actual message data
    // console.log(event.data.val());

    // console.log(event.params);//pushId and messageID
    pushID = event.params.pushId;
    // console.log(pushID);

    return loadUsers().then(users => {

        let tokens = [];

        for (let user of users) {
            if (user.pushToken != projectData.PushToken){
                tokens.push(user.pushToken);
            }

        }
        let payload = {
            notification: {
                title: projectData.RealName,
                body: projectData.MessageBody,
                sound: 'SnowSocialNotificationTone.wav',
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    });
});
function loadUsers() {
    // console.log('started loadUsers()');

    let dbRef = admin.database().ref(`/${pushID}/GroupMembers`);

    let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
            let data = snap.val();
            console.log(snap.val());
            let users = [];

            for (var property in data) {
                users.push(data[property]);
            }
            resolve(users);
        }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
    return defer;
}
```